# Disable Controls on Featured Video Plus WordPress Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/featured-video-plus/

On my latest WordPress version 4.7.2 but I will like to hide the controls.

When I check my code I can see this.

```
<video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-65-1" loop="1" autoplay="1" preload="metadata" controls="controls" width="10240" height="5760"><source type="video/mp4" src="Untitled9.mp4?_=1"><a href="Untitled9.mp4">Untitled9.mp4</a></video>
```

The issue is that the plugin does not offer the option to hide controls so I need to eliminate this in the code --> **controls="controls"**

I have not been able to find it inside the plugin so I will like to know if someone knows how to fix this.

I don't want to show the controls when mouse overlay or just hide them forever.

Thanks

******** **UPDATE** ********

**Here is a picture of the plugin and its HTML Markup**

[image]

********* **These are my Plugin Settings** *********

[image]

********* **What I did is I uploaded a video to the Media and then paste the video URL inside the Featured Video section - SEE IMAGE BELOW** *********

[image]

***** **SOLUTION TO THIS PROBLEM** *****

NOTE: Unfortunately CSS does not works for this, so I ended up not changing the plugin, please if anyone has a better solution please share.

Again this is not the best solution as I need to change the media.php file from WordPress but for me is a small price I am willing to pay.

To eliminate controls inside the video tag go to /wp-includes/media.php

And find these PHP code around line 2580 or so:

```
$html .= sprintf( '<video %s controls="controls">', join( ' ', $attr_strings ) );
```

and just change it to this

```
$html .= sprintf( '<video %s>', join( ' ', $attr_strings ) );
```

Make a backup and every time you update WordPress, remember this small change as you will need to change it back

Comment: Your question is about the Featured Video Plus plugin. Your solution to this problem comes from editing core WordPress files. The plugin is not related to your solution. The solution is better addressed by using the filter `wp_video_shortcode` so you don't touch the WordPress core files.

Comment: Yes I know, but I could not find a better and faster solution by changing the plugin and no one else is giving a solution with the plugin. A solution that makes go away the controls attribute. So I had to find an alternative, as I said it works for me. Yes I know there are better ways and hopefully someone post a better solution but CSS is not working on this problem I have.

Comment: Don't post your solution as part of the question, but as its own answer, please.

Comment: You guys here are confusing, in past questions some users told me to post the update on my question and some others like you say post its own answer. I used to create answers but everyone in here seems to have their own opinion and try to boss around. I just posted the answer/update to help. If people like it the way I did it, good if not that's good for me too. Peace out :)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Unfortunately CSS does not works for this problem as my template eliminate many unneeded CSS and JS WordPress files, so I ended up not changing the plugin, please if anyone has a better solution please share.

Again this is not the best solution as I need to change the media.php file from WordPress but for me is a small price I am willing to pay.

To eliminate controls inside the video tag go to /wp-includes/media.php

And find these PHP code around line 2580 or so:

$html .= sprintf( '', join( ' ', $attr_strings ) );

and just change it to this

$html .= sprintf( '', join( ' ', $attr_strings ) );

Make a backup and every time you update WordPress, remember this small change as you will need to change it back